# How to Call Fragment from AnotherActivity to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have one Activity with `RecyclerView` items. 
In `AnotherActivity`, I have many fragments. When the RecyclerView is clicked, `AnotherActivity`'s fragment should open. 
Please help !!

This is Recycler Adapter from Activity 
**Edited code included**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Item item = itemList.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(item.getName());
    // 
    Picasso.with(mContext)
           .load(item.getPic())
           .into(holder.imageView);

    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new 
       View.OnClickListener() {
        int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //  Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello" + 
      item.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    // Toast.makeText(mContext, "zero", 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, 
                WebSlider.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                     //call  particular fragment 
                    ...........
                    }
                }
    }
```

***Another Activity with viewpager***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_slider);

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);


 Viewpager adapter ...

 public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
    ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new Chapter1(), "");
    adapter.addFragment(new Chapter2(), "");
    adapter.addFragment(new Chapter3(), "");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ........................
}
```

Now When i calling function is called from Fragment activity so that it should go to MianActivity

Comment: post your recycler adapter and the activity code

Comment: have u use tab layout in your another activity?

Comment: i have added adapter and activity code ..

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

If you use `TabLayout` in your another activity than follow my code

In  one Activity with `Recyclerview` items

```
Intent i = new Intent(your_context, YourAnotherActivity.class);
i.putBooleanExtra("key", true);
startActivity(i);
```

In your otherActivity.java

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getBooleanExtra("key",false))
{
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);//pass viewPagerFragemtnt position 
}
```

Comment: thanx for the suggestion but I'm not getting the correct position fragment.,

Comment: all the positions are coming correct except the second position.3rd position is shown first when the back button is clicked then exact position comes.what is the problem here?